# thick vertical line symbol for norm of vector

Tags: delimiters

Some old text books use single thick vertical lines for writing norms of vectors. I would like to define a pair of delimiters which behaves like `\lvert` and `\rvert`, but with thicker lines. The new delimiters should of course adapt to the size of the formula, just like `\lvert` and `\rvert` do. Can this be done?

Comment: Are `\bracevert` delimiters thick enough?

Comment: Yes, they would be thick enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an extensible delimiter called `\bracevert`, but it needs some coaxing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\oldnormaux}{\bracevert}{\bracevert}

\NewDocumentCommand{\oldnorm}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldnormaux*{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {\oldnormaux*{\vphantom{dq}#3}}
       {\oldnormaux[#2]{#3}}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

$\oldnorm{v}\oldnorm[\big]{v}\oldnorm[\Big]{v}\oldnorm*{\dfrac{1}{2}v}$

\end{document}
```

See the documentation of `mathtools` for `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, with respect to the syntax; our `\oldnorm` command works the same.

[image]

A more complex solution which also takes care of the spacing; the example also compares it with the standard `\Vert` symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\oldnorm}{sO{}m}{%
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldnormaux{\left|}{\right|}{#3}}
    {\oldnormaux{#2|}{#2|}{#3}}}
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\oldnormaux}[3]{\mathpalette\oldnormaux@i{{#1}{#2}{#3}}}
\newcommand{\oldnormaux@i}[2]{\oldnormaux@ii#1#2}
\newcommand{\oldnormaux@ii}[4]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#2#4#3$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$\m@th\|$}%
  \mathopen{\hbox to\wd\tw@{\hss\vrule height \ht\z@ depth \dp\z@ width .3\wd\tw@\hss}}%
  #4
  \mathclose{\hbox to\wd\tw@{\hss\vrule height \ht\z@ depth \dp\z@ width .3\wd\tw@\hss}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

$\oldnorm{v}\oldnorm[\big]{v}\oldnorm[\Big]{v}\oldnorm*{\dfrac{1}{2}v}^2$

$|\oldnorm{x}|$

$|\lVert x\rVert|$

$\oldnorm*{\dfrac{1}{2}v}^2 \left\lVert\dfrac{1}{2}v\right\rVert^2$

$x_{\oldnorm{v}}$ $x_{\lVert v\rVert}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The thickness of the vertical bars is exactly what I want. However, the horizontal spacing does not look good. Also, the vertical length of the delimiters is different from the vertical lines produced by \lrvert and \lvert.

Comment: You can always insert a negative space between the delimiters and the expression inside: `{\oldnormaux*{\mkern-5mu\vphantom{dq}#3\mkern-5mu}}` for example. As for the vertical line length you're probably out of luck with `\bracevert`. The delimiter is constructed from a not-so-tiny parts stacked together, so its length changes discretely.

Comment: @linusk Added a more complicated version that should satisfy your needs.